# How to deal with large RegionSize in VirtualQueryEx?

Tags: c, winapi, memory, readprocessmemory

I'm writing a simple memoryscanner in c, where I'm using VirtualQueryEx to scan an arbitrary process's memory.

`VirtualQueryEx (hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)`

I loop through all of the memory blocks in process like this:

`addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize`

But the problem is that one block of memory is much larger than the size of SIZE_T and can't fit into meminfo.RegionSize.

This is what it looks like in process hacker:

[process hacker 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al2L2.png)

As you can see it jumps from 0x7ffe2000 to 0x19a1e00000 creates a RegionSize of 0x1921e1e000 which is much larger than an 2^32.

I tested with other processes than notepad.exe and they had that same huge jump after about 3 blocks of memory that are always 4k in size. I tried starting at an address after this huge jump and it worked fine, but the problem is that the jumps are allocated differently for each process so it's not a portable solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you use a larger size for calculations?

Comment: SIZE_T is 32bit size for an x86 process and 64bit size for an x64 process. There cannot be a block of memory larger than SIZE_T (unless you're running as x86 and try to use 64bit sized integer)

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. I have 64 bit windows, but my gcc compiler can only compile in 32 bit for some reason and I get error with -m64 flag so I might have to check that out. Thx!

Comment: If you're querying a 64-bit application from a 32-bit application, you may need to use [one of the explicit memory info structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-memory_basic_information#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I was compiling the c program with mingw which is 32-bit, but I'm using a 64-bit system. That's why the RegionSize couldn't fit in SIZE_T.